# How to join attributes to a many-to-many tables keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I currently have a table called borders which functions as a many-to-many relation for two country-entities:

```
CREATE TABLE borders
(
    Country1 VARCHAR(4),
    Country2 VARCHAR(4),
    Length DECIMAL 
        CHECK (Length > 0),

    CONSTRAINT BorderKey PRIMARY KEY (Country1,Country2) 
);
```

Where each tuple in the table looks something like:

```
|      country1       |    country2    |    length      |
|---------------------|----------------|----------------|
|          AL         |       MK       |     3271       |
|          GR         |       TR       |     1712       |
```

Now I would like to create a query that projects a table where you can also see the GDP for both of these countries, gathered from the Economy table which looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE Economy
(
    Country VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT EconomyKey PRIMARY KEY,
    GDP DECIMAL CONSTRAINT EconomyGDP
        CHECK (GDP >= 0)
);
```

The resulting table should look something like:

```
|      country1       |    country2    |      GDP1      |      GDP2      |     length      |
|---------------------|----------------|----------------|----------------|------------------
|          AL         |       MK       |       428      |       734      |       3271      |
|          GR         |       TR       |       300      |       823      |       1712      |
```

Where GDP1 corresponds to country1 and GDP2 corresponds to country2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the Ecomny table twice for every country

Like

> ```
> CREATE TABLE borders(
>   Country1 VARCHAR(4),
>   Country2 VARCHAR(4),
>   Length DECIMAL 
>   CHECK (Length > 0),
>   CONSTRAINT BorderKey PRIMARY KEY (Country1,Country2) 
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO borders VALUES('A1','A2',1000)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Economy(
>   Country VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT EconomyKey PRIMARY KEY,
>   GDP DECIMAL CONSTRAINT EconomyGDP
>   CHECK (GDP >= 0)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Economy VALUES ('A1',100);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Economy VALUES('A2',101);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT b.Country1,b.Country2, e1.GDP as GDP1,e2.GDP AS GDP2,b.Length
> FROM borders b 
> JOIN Economy e1 ON b.Country1 = e1.Country
> JOIN Economy e2 ON b.Country2 = e2.Country
> ```
>
> ```
> COUNTRY1 | COUNTRY2 | GDP1 | GDP2 | LENGTH
> :------- | :------- | ---: | ---: | -----:
> A1       | A2       |  100 |  101 |   1000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f80a055c381a1ad0cc30d9b20a92e64)*